# Android using recycle bitmap

Tags: android

I have a Android app running which involves drawing bitmap repeatedly every 20 milliseconds.

How do I make it so Android DOES NOT automatically recycle my bitmaps?

I keep the bitmaps in a hash map with strings(names of the bit maps) keying to the bitmap files.

Answer (score 0):

It will recycle them unless you are using them elsewhere.

You need to maintain some object that is pointing to the bitmap, then it will not be recycled when you call setContentView() (or your equivalent) with a new bitmap.

So, when you create the bitmap, store a reference to that bitmap somewhere, such as in an array, and keep that array around.  Then put your bitmap into the display.